# Merge multiple csv files and add a new column

Tags: python, csv

I have a bunch of csv files that i need to merge into one file but with an additional date column

xxxxx20150216.csv

xxxxx20130802.csv

xxxxx20130803.csv

xxxxx20130804.csv

I am using the following code from  (http://cbrownley.wordpress.com/2014/03/09/pythons-voracious-glob-module/) to merge them

```
import csv
import glob
import os
import sys

data_path = ""
outfile_path = "alldata.csv"
filewriter = csv.writer(open(outfile_path,'wb'))
file_counter = 0
for input_file in glob.glob(os.path.join(data_path,'*.csv')):
        with open(input_file,'rU') as csv_file:
                filereader = csv.reader(csv_file)
                if file_counter < 1:
                        for row in filereader:
                                filewriter.writerow(row)
                else:
                        header = next(filereader,None)
                        for row in filereader:
                                filewriter.writerow(row)
        file_counter += 1
```

But now I need to extract the date from the filename and add it as column along with the other rows. What could be the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about...:

```
    with open(input_file,'rU') as csv_file:
        filereader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(input_file)
        date = name[-8:]
        if file_counter < 1:
            for i, row in enumerate(filereader):
                if i==0: row.append('Date')
                else: row.append(date)
                filewriter.writerow(row)
            else:
                header = next(filereader,None)
                for row in filereader:
                    row.append(date)
                    filewriter.writerow(row)
```

The only tricky part is taking the headers from the first CSV file!-)

Comment: Accept without upvote -- weird from somebody w/40+ rep!  Any specific reason why you accepted and posted a thanks comment but chose not to upvote?!

Comment: Sorry.. new & embarrassed stack overflow user here :( still getting my hands around how this works. Thanks again for your help, save me a few hours!

Comment: note that the `rU` ("universal newlines") access mode is deprecated. You should utilize the `newline` argument for that: `open(input_file,'r', newline='...')`. See documentation here https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open